# Table columns collapsed when button or image clicked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this function which is responsible of making the table tr and th collapse. I want to collapse the table columns when button is clicked. I think because I am using `$('tr th'),click(function()` so when I clicking wherever in `th` it is collapsing. I want to collapse when we click the button or image like this `(function myFunction(){})`.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $('table tbody tr:odd').addClass('alt');

    $('table tbody tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});

$('tr th:not(:eq(0),:eq(1),:eq(2),:eq(3),:eq(4),:eq(5))').click(function() {

    var index = (this.cellIndex + 1);
    var cells = $('table tr > :nth-child(' + index + ')');
    cells.toggleClass('collapsed');

    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>+</b>');
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>-</b>');
    }

    if ($('table tr > th:not(.collapsed)').length)
        $('table').removeClass('collapsed');
    else
        $('table').addClass('collapsed');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you add a onclick event on button instead of adding a click listener using jquery. 
you can do something like

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleExpand('anyReqParam1', 'anyReqParam2')" class="toggle"></button>
```

and in script define the function

```
<script>
  function toggleExpand(anyReqParam1, anyReqParam2) {
     // toggle code goes here
  }
</script>
```

or alternatively you can also do

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {

});
```

using JQuery. Here **toggle** is the class name that i gave to the button